# Getting restricted combinations in an array

Tags: java, arrays

So I am currently working on creating a domain of possible values of a variable, which in my case is an array of chars. Because the data I will be working with isnt really small and even if it were, with 2 values acceptable in every char slot, an 11 slot array would have 2^11 possible values, which is really not an ammount of arrays you would like to have.

Because of this instead of cutting down the domain with teh constraints afterwards Im trying to generate the domain already based on the constraints.

The constraints basically state blocks of a number of the same char and the order of the blocks. It looks something like this:

```
#,2,G,1
```

Lets say this is the restriction I have and the array has a size of 5, the empty array looks like so

```
[_][_][_][_][_]
```

I can now create one element of the domain by simply stacking everything to the beginning following the constraints.

```
[#][#][G][_][_]
```

Now however, I would need to generate all the other possible variants of this, them being:

```
[#][#][_][G][_]
[#][#][_][_][G]
[_][#][#][G][_]
[_][#][#][_][G]
[_][_][#][#][G]
```

Like this I have successfully managed to cut down the elements of the domain from 2^5 to 6.

The question then: Would anyone be able to provide a way for this? Doesnt have to be code, just a basic idea is probably going to be enough

Comment: Fantastic! What is the question?

Comment: Sorry, shouldve been clearer. Edited.

Comment: There is always the [brute-force](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_search) approach, though I find the solutions from Tim Bender s naswer more interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Still not quite sure of what you are asking. At the moment, it seems like you have a [Constraint Satisfaction Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem). Or perhaps a grammar. In either case, the solution is to use a recursive algorithm to enumerate the possibilities at each level (array index).

Comment: Thanks Tim. This is the code I have made based on this, for anyone else who might be tackling a similar problem: http://pastebin.com/23KfVTm7